# Unable to Load Key Value Pair XML as java preferences

Tags: java, xml

I am new to XML. I am trying to define key value pairs in XML so that this file can be used as configuration file for my project. I am getting errors while I am loading this xml file in java.  Please let me know how to fix this issue.

XML file (data.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object>
<field name="property1" value="1"> 
<field name="property2" value="2"> 
<field name="property3" value="3"> 
<field name="property4" value="4"> 
</object>
</xml>
```

Java Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class PreferencesExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Preferences ps = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(PreferencesExample.class);
        // Load  file object
        File fileObj = new File("data.xml");
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileObj);
            ps.importPreferences(fis);
            System.out.println("Prefereces:"+ps);
            System.out.println("Get property1:"+ps.getInt("property1",10));

        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I got below error while I load this xml in java.

>

```
 java.util.prefs.InvalidPreferencesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
 lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 9; Document root element "object", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
        at java.util.prefs.XmlSupport.importPreferences(XmlSupport.java:216)
        at java.util.prefs.Preferences.importPreferences(Preferences.java:1259)
```

What would be possible root cause? I am suspecting XML file format but I don't have expertise in XML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your xml file should be in the below format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE preferences SYSTEM 'http://java.sun.com/dtd/preferences.dtd'>
<preferences EXTERNAL_XML_VERSION="1.0">
<root type="user">
<map />
<node name="com">
  <map />
  <node name="mypack">
    <map />
    <node name="test">
      <map>
        <entry key="property1" value="80" />
        <entry key="property2" value="Red" />
      </map>
    </node>
  </node>
</node>
</root>
</preferences>
```

and the node names are the package name of the class PreferencesExample. In this example, it is com/mypack/test.

this link might be helpful for [java preferences](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2002/10/preferences.html)

Comment: Code is working now.Prefereces:User Preference Node: /com/mypack/test
Get property1:80